# Rxjs Mocha tests will not run on WebStorm

Tags: rxjs, mocha.js, webstorm

I have been trying to get the spec tests running from the rxjs repository on the WebStorm IDE.

```
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs.git
```

The issue is that I can run the tests using the included script, and manually through the command line but configuring WebStorm is not working.

Below is the error message that I am getting most frequently. I have included the default opts file for Mocha, and below is the result.

```
ReferenceError: asDiagram is not defined
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/test/Desktop/Test/rxjs/spec/Observable-spec.ts:636:3)
    at Object.create (/Users/test/Desktop/Test/rxjs/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/common.js:112:19)
    at context.describe.context.context (/Users/test/Desktop/Test/rxjs/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:44:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/test/Desktop/Test/rxjs/spec/Observable-spec.ts:635:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/test/Desktop/Test/rxjs/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:430:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/test/Desktop/Test/rxjs/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:433:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem occurs because Webstorm is passing `--ui bdd` to mocha, overwriting your custom ui specified in `spec/support/default.opts`. To work out the issue, you have to change **User interface:** option in **Mocha** run configuration from default (`bdd`) to your custom one (`spec/helpers/testScheduler-ui.ts`) - field is editable, you can type/paste the value. Configuration that works fine for me:

[image]

Comment: That worked thanks. As an aside were you able to get debug to work. That is not working for me .

Comment: well.. it just works (using the configuratio above) - I added a pair of breakpoints to `spec/Observable-spec.ts`, selected the run configuration and pressed **debug** - after a while the breakpoints were successfully hit:) Tests instantiation took noticeable time on the first run, but ran fluently on next attempts

Comment: Can you tell me which version of webstorm and node you are running?

Comment: 2018.1.5, 2018.2 EAP; Node.js 8.10.0